# Direct collision on smooth surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, collision

Hello I have a problem on my hands an I cannot figure out the answer.

Two spheres of equal mass on on a smooth surface.  sphere 1 is moving at $2v \ m/s$. Sphere 2 is stationary and 1m from a bollard.  In this problem $e=e$

I have found that the speeds after collision 1 are $u(1-e)$ and $u(1+e)$.

I need to prove the distance between both spheres is $\frac{2e}{1+e}$ when sphere 2 hits the bollard.

What I have done is:$$\frac{1}{u(1+e)} = t$$$$(\frac{1}{u(1+e)})(u(1-e))$$

But that leads to nothing, what is the correct way to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: shouldn't it be $(\frac{1}{u(1+e)})(u(1-e))$?

Comment: Then the equation you get is correct, except that you will also subtract $1$, the distance travelled by B

Comment: I just get $-\frac{ue-u}{ue+u}$

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is a well known problem, and the two balls simply exchange kinetic energies, so the moving ball comes to rest, and the stationary ball takes off at the same velocity that the first ball had initially.

There is a complication to this problem.   The above explanation only works, if the moving ball is sliding, and NOT rolling, because if it is rolling, then you have to allow for the conservation of the angular momentum as well.   Without friction, there is no way to convey the angular momentum to the second ball.

So if the first ball is rolling, and everything truly is frictionless, the first ball would stop on the spot, and continue to spin at the same rotation rate it had before, and the second ball would take off and not roll, but slide frictionlessly across the surface.

Comment: So how do I prove the distance between them.